# How to generalize QGIS 3.0 Model so that I can install on multiple computers without setting up on every computer?

Tags: style, qgis-3, qgis-modeler, generalization, style-manager

[image]

I am trying to create a model to work on multiple computers with little editing. I am working in QGIS 3.0. I am trying to get the model to first set the style for the layers based on a predefined qlr. Is there a way to generalize the style file path so that it seeks a folder called "Layer Styles."

For example in ArcMap i use %Scratchworkspace% for some generalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Layer Styles" folder I would like the model to point to is saved on the C drive so it does not need to be changed

**C:\Layer Styles**

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables:

- `@user_account_name` to get the account name of the user, such as
  `'C:/Users/'|| @user_account_name ||'/Desktop/file.qml'`.
- `@project_folder` to get the folder of the project you work with is saved in, such as `@project_folder ||'/file.qml'`
- `@project_home` to get the home folder of your project

*Or create a new variable within project properties. But since you would have to create this one on each computer, it is not really easier...*